# What force does a tall building exert on air?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics

I once heard that a tall building, let's say 10 stories, actually causes wind to blow by virtue of simply existing. It also was said that is why metropolitan downtown areas tend to be windy. What are the facts relating to thins?

Answer (score 2):

It is not a force exerted by the building that causes the wind, it is just the way the air current is manipulated. The air currents have to go somewhere. Due to the building being tall, they are unable to flow over it. Thus, they travel up along it, down along it, and around it. Moreover, if there is a high density of tall buildings in an area, you get the wind tunneling effect, as the air currents are forced through narrow spaces, causing strong wind. In some cases, the buildings themselves have a special design, that purposely allow the air currents to flow through airways that have been constructed for this purpose, thus creating wind. If you were wondering the point of these, they help reduce the stress on the frame of the building.

Comment: I like your answer but technically buildings can cause air movement on their own (especially on days with a lot of incident sunlight) through differential heating/cooling and the convective and subsiding motions that result.

Comment: @farrenthorpe Can't deny that, not even going to try by making excuses. Just didn't come to my mind. +1

Comment: but wouldn't the convective motions be significantly smaller than the overall wind speed? Just thinking about the scales which generate such behavior - scales of weather vs scales of buildings...

Comment: @levitopher Well that definitely depends upon what you are comparing it to. In normal circumstances, tall buildings and skyscrapers have a significant affect on the wind speed of the area. The convection motions can generate surprisingly high wind speeds. But obviously if you take into account hurricanes, and other incidents of abnormally high wind speeds, then the effect is negligible.